# mod rewrite absolute paths and links also to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my app to be portable from root to subdir without having to change anything.
I want to use alsolute paths, because in case the app is installed in root everything works out of the box. So root installation has priority one.

In order to get the subfolder scenario working I tried several things.

Let the app dynamicaly write a .htaccess file based on folderstructure during initial install.To get the right RewriteBase automaticaly set.This file was looking like that:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|js|ico|font|gif|jpg|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Of course no static file are found in that case, because the absolute paths are going to root instead of subfolder.

Then I found out how to let .htaccess find its own RewriteBase and tried the following

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

## Determine the RewriteBase automatically/dynamically
## -- taken from symfony .htaccess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# Allow /images/*, /css/* & /js/* but deny everything else, e.g. /lib/*
# -- found in stackoverflow
# ORIGINAL VERSION IS:
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^%{ENV:BASE}(public|images|css|js)/ [NC]
#RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]
# ----- DID NOT WORK ------
# -----CANGED IT TO 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^%{ENV:BASE}(public|images|css|js)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ./index.php - [R=404,L]

# Rewrite all other requests to index.php if is file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

If I hit the landingPage all static files are loaded. But as soon as click on menu 'Home/' Home is prepended to the path of static files. like so

```
http://www.local.dev/subfolder/Home/public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css  ---- not found
```

And that is only if I remove all leading slashes from static files. I mean alter from '/public' to 'public'

Dont really know what to do anymore

very much appreciate any help

Due to the downvote ;)
Forgot to say that I dont want to use a `<base>` tag either. I want to keep all absolute paths in template. Switch app to whichever folder and have it working ...... should be possible somehow ..... it works in symfony , drupal ...

**Update:**

Found a solution:
putting another .htaccess file into the webroot folder, in my case htdocs.

```
htdocs  
   project  
   anotherproject
   elseproject  
   .htaccess
```

with the simple rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/$1
```

everything works now - but I am not quite satisfied with it since this file kills all other projects.
Is there an other way to achieve the same ??

**update**

to prevent other projects from this rule just add project folders to the RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/otherproject/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/$1
```

Comment: Only other way to fix this is to always use absolute paths in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: @anubhava That is what I meant. I only want use / have absolute paths. Is there a possibility to achieve this without the external (in root) .htaccess file ? could you give me an example if there is ? Thank you

Comment: @user2716249 did you end up finding a solution to this? I don't really want to add every project under a `RewriteCond` to prevent them from this rule